# Compiler error C2064 in functional when try to initialise a std::thread in a class constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I am writing a class which uses a thread and I wanted to try the new C++11 `std::thread`.  I am compiling with Microsoft Visual Studio Pro 2013 v12.0.31101.00 Update 4. The update is from Nov 2014 so is fairly up-to-date.  I can use `std::thread` for simple uses but in my code below I get compiler errors.

If I comment out the initialization of the thread, as in:

```
serial(int port) : port_(port) {} //, reader_thread(&serial::reader_thread_func) {}
```

Then it compiles ok.

How can I fix this?

Here is my code.

serial.hpp:

```
/* serial port class */
#ifndef SERIAL_
#define SERIAL_

#include <thread>

class serial
{
public:
    serial(int port) : port_(port), reader_thread(&serial::reader_thread_func) {}
    ~serial();
    bool open();
    bool close();

private:
    std::thread reader_thread;
    void reader_thread_func();
    int port_;
};

#endif // SERIAL_
```

serial.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "serial.hpp"


void serial::reader_thread_func() {
    std::cout << "reader thread running with thread id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
}

serial::~serial() {
    close();
}

bool serial::open() {

    close(); // in case we are already open

    std::cout << "opening port " << port_ << '\n';
    return true;
}

bool serial::close() {
    std::cout << "closing port " << port_ << '\n';
    return false;
}
```

main.cpp to drive:

```
#include "serial.hpp"

int main() {
    serial s(3);
    s.open();

    s.close();
}
```

Compiler errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: thread_in_class, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  serial.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(1149): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
1>          class does not define an 'operator()' or a user defined conversion operator to a pointer-to-function or reference-to-function that takes appropriate number of arguments
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(1137) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall serial::* )(void),void,serial,>,>::_Do_call<,>(std::tuple<>,std::_Arg_idx<>)' being compiled
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(1137) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall serial::* )(void),void,serial,>,>::_Do_call<,>(std::tuple<>,std::_Arg_idx<>)' being compiled
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(195) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall serial::* )(void),void,serial,>,>::operator ()<>(void)' being compiled
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(195) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall serial::* )(void),void,serial,>,>::operator ()<>(void)' being compiled
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(192) : while compiling class template member function 'unsigned int std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<_Target> *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall serial::* )(void),void,serial,>,>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(187) : see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned int std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<_Target> *)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall serial::* )(void),void,serial,>,>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(205) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_LaunchPad<_Target>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall serial::* )(void),void,serial,>,>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\thread(49) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Launch<std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall serial::* )(void),void,serial,>,>>(_Thrd_t *,_Target &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall serial::* )(void),void,serial,>,>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\angus\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\thread_in_class\thread_in_class\serial.hpp(10) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::thread::thread<void(__thiscall serial::* )(void),>(_Fn &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fn=void (__thiscall serial::* )(void)
1>          ]
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(1149): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
1>          class does not define an 'operator()' or a user defined conversion operator to a pointer-to-function or reference-to-function that takes appropriate number of arguments
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(1137) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall serial::* )(void),void,serial,>,>::_Do_call<,>(std::tuple<>,std::_Arg_idx<>)' being compiled
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(1137) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall serial::* )(void),void,serial,>,>::_Do_call<,>(std::tuple<>,std::_Arg_idx<>)' being compiled
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(195) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall serial::* )(void),void,serial,>,>::operator ()<>(void)' being compiled
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(195) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall serial::* )(void),void,serial,>,>::operator ()<>(void)' being compiled
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(192) : while compiling class template member function 'unsigned int std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<_Target> *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall serial::* )(void),void,serial,>,>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(187) : see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned int std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<_Target> *)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall serial::* )(void),void,serial,>,>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(205) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_LaunchPad<_Target>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall serial::* )(void),void,serial,>,>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\thread(49) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Launch<std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall serial::* )(void),void,serial,>,>>(_Thrd_t *,_Target &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall serial::* )(void),void,serial,>,>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\angus\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\thread_in_class\thread_in_class\serial.hpp(10) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::thread::thread<void(__thiscall serial::* )(void),>(_Fn &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fn=void (__thiscall serial::* )(void)
1>          ]
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reader_thread_func` is a class member function. It cannot be called as a standalone function, only on an instance of class `serial`. You need to provide an instance of `serial` to `thread` as the first argument:

```
reader_thread = std::thread(&serial::reader_thread_func, this);
//                                                       ↑↑↑↑
```

That's what the error "term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments" means - in the context of *INVOKE*, `reader_thread_func` takes one argument: a `serial`.